# When does my travel within Schengen start

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, croatia

I'm from India. I intend to travel to Croatia and Italy, by flying from India to Croatia (outside Schengen), via a transit through Frankfurt. I will then fly to Italy from Croatia.
When I apply for a Schengen visa from the Italian consulate, will my stay in the Schengen region be considered to have started from the time I transit through Frankfurt, or only when I arrive in Italy ? 
Would my itinerary be considered as 2 entries into the Schengen zone (since I leave the schengen zone when flying from Frankfurt to Croatia) ?
I ask this because I need to have a valid, Multi entry Schengen visa to visit Croatia without a separate Croatian visa.

Comment: That’s a good question!

Answer (score 5):

When you arrive at Frankfurt from India and immediately continue on a flight to Croatia, you *will not enter the Shengen area* as part of that transit. You will stay in the international transit area of the airport.

At least this is the case if both your flights are part of a single booked journey, such that you don't need to collect and re-check baggage.

If you need a reason to get a two-entry Schengen visa, you could either amend your plans with an overnight stopover in Frankfurt, or perhaps state in your application that you will book the Frankfurt-Croatia ticket separately and therefore need to enter Schengen to recheck baggage. If you can make the latter seem like a reasonable plan, given the choices of airlines, etc. you present in your itinerary, there's a good change that the Italian consulate would issue a 2-entry visa.

If you do need to enter Schengen in Frankfurt, then certainly you will need to *exit* it again to go to Croatia. Arriving in Italy later will be another entry.

Comment: I had intended to travel to Croatia on a single ticket - via Frankfurt. Its a lot more expensive to split the ticket. Schengen stats suggest that Italy gives multi entry visas to 95% of applicants from India, so I'm more concerned about my visa being valid only from the time I land in Italy (I'm a frequent traveller to the schengen region though its the first time I'm facing this situation).